# Aumento de memoria RAM timerTask

Tags: java, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla de la base datos SQL, el problema es, que tengo que consultar los datos a tiempo real, por lo tanto he creado una tarea cada 1 segundo, pero resulta que la memoria RAM se incremente hasta que se llena.

```
    public void sentenciaTiempoReal() {

    // Clase en la que está el código a ejecutar 
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLTIEMPOREAL);
                muestraTiempoReal(rs);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Contador "+contador++);
        }
    };
    // Aquí se pone en marcha el timer cada segundo. 
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, MILISEGUNDOS);     
}

private void muestraTiempoReal(ResultSet rs) throws ParseException {
    int estado;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            estado = rs.getInt(2);
            jlRobot.setText("Robot: " + rs.getString(3));
            //fecha y hora 
            jlFechaUltAct.setText("Última actualización: " + rs.getTimestamp(4));
            Calendar calfFinal = Calendar.getInstance();
            calfFinal.setTime(rs.getTimestamp(4));
            String fechaFinal = String.valueOf(rs.getTimestamp(4));

            jlTiempoEstado.setText(operaciones.entreDosFechas(fechaFinal, operaciones.getFechaActual()));

            //huellas
            String huellasActivas = String.valueOf(operaciones.decimalABinario(rs.getInt(11)));
            jlHuellasActivas.setText("Huellas activas: " + String.valueOf(operaciones.contadorHuellas(huellasActivas)));

            //huellas
            jlBuenas.setText("BUENAS: " + rs.getDouble(5));
            jlProcesadas.setText("PROCESADAS: " + rs.getDouble(6));
            jlMalas.setText("MALAS: " + rs.getDouble(7));
            jlCiclo.setText("Velocidad de la máquina: " + rs.getDouble(8) + "ms");
            if (estado == 1) {
                jbEstado.setBackground(Color.green);
                jbEstado.setText("MARCHA");
            }
            if (estado == 2) {
                jbEstado.setBackground(Color.RED);
                jbEstado.setText("PARO O STAND-BY");
            }
            //evento zona de fallo cesar
            eventoFalloVibrador(rs.getInt(9));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se crean nuevos objetos cada vez que haces la query, y estos quedan sin liberar. Puedes intentar poner a **null** los objetos que ya no uses. Tambien puedes forzar al colector de basura justo debajo de `System.out.println("Contador "+contador++);` con la función `System.gc()` (esto es una mala practica[..]). Tambien puedes cerrar la conexion con `finally { if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); } }` justo despues del `catch` de `run()` [Cerrar conexion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Comment: Resulta de que en el método  "eventoFalloVibrador(rs.getInt(9));" estaba cargando un par de AudioSystem cada segundo, y claro se incrementaba la memoria, de todas formas también he cerrado el Result y el Statement. Muchas gracias Crack!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como estás utilizando SQL Server recomiendo leer sobre SQL Server Query Notification
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

También revisa Apache ActiveMQ es gratis y te puede ayudar en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a documentarme.

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que estas dejando el **ResultSet** abierto, asi que cada vez que pides uno, creas uno nuevo y el anterior se queda en memoria ligado a la conexión.

Se podrían realizar muchas optimizaciones pero lo básico seria usar un PreparedStatement con o sin parámetros, dependiendo de si SQLTIEMPOREAL es estática o cambia de parámetros, y el cerrar el ResultSet para liberar los recursos.

```
public void sentenciaTiempoReal() {

     PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQLTIEMPOREAL,
            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

    // Clase en la que está el código a ejecutar 
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                muestraTiempoReal(rs);
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Contador " + contador++);
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, MILISEGUNDOS);     
}
```

Ni que decir tiene que este ejemplo no es perfecto y como decía antes se puede optimizar mucho mas. Se puede mejorar el proceso, la gestión de la conexión, la SQL,...

Pero como mínimo seria el mantener la conexión (objeto con), usar el preparedStatement para no crear todo el tiempo la consulta y sobre todo cerrar el ResultSet para liberar los datos de la consulta realizada.